# HP - UX - Size calcucation using bash script

Tags: bash, hp-ux

I am trying to display size in human-readable form on HP-UX. We have a few legacy systems which we use for sftp transfers. These servers are connected T1 leased line and transfers are very slow. I have to occasionally check the size to verify if the transfer is done or not.
As HP-UX cant display the size in kb or GB, we have to manually divide the output to verify.
I am just trying to build a small script to display the size in GB.

```
read -p "Enter File Path/Location " location
output=$(ls -l $location | cut -d ' ' -f 18)
#output=$(ls -l /central/home/sftp/file.daily | cut -d ' ' -f 18)
echo "Size in GB is:  ${output}"
#echo "Size in GB is:  ${output} / (1024*1024*1024)"  not working "

bash-4.4$ ./script
Enter File Path/Location /central/home/sftp/file.daily
Size in GB is:  153844074
bash-4.4$
```

Guys/Gals, I am not a pro, just learning stuff to enhance my knowledge in bash scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command `echo "Size in GB is:  ${output} / (1024*1024*1024)"` is not working because the expression is just a string. To do calculations in bash, use an arithmetic context `$(( ... ))`. However, `bash` cannot handle floating point numbers, therefore I'd resort to `bc`.

Also, `ls | cut -f 18` seems a bit strange. This would retrieve the 18th field. The output of my `ls -l` has only 9 fields and the file size is the 5th field.
Instead of parsing `ls` you can parse `du`, which is simpler and less error prone. `du -k` prints the size in kB (= 1024 Byte).

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
size_kB=$(du -k "$1" | cut -f 1)
size_GB=$(echo "scale=1; $size_kB / 1024 / 1024;" | bc)
echo "File $1 has size $size_GB GB"
```

Store this script in a executable file, then use it as

```
bash$ path/to/myscript.sh someFile
File someFile has size 12.3 GB
```

Passing the filename as an argument allows you to use tab completion. This wouldn't have been possible with `read`.